# No. of requests serviced per hour in SOAP UI

Tags: load, soapui

How can I get the max. no. of requests serviced per hour by the application for the following scenarios.

1) One thread user for one test case(one test case has one teststep. i.e., one request)

2) One thread user for one test case(one test case has 10 teststeps. i.e., ten requests)

3) Five thread user for one test case(one test case has 10 teststeps. i.e., ten requests)

I've an idea of using Simple strategy with random zero(0), test delay = 0, Limit 3600 seconds with threads 1,1,5 for the corresponding scenarios as above in SOAP UI LOAD test.

Ideally to determine the # of requests handled by the server per hour, I assume that the number of requests handled in scenario 2 = number of requests handled in scenario 1 as it is for one thread group and the # of requests handled per hour is our main focus, but the results are far varying.

Can any one please guide me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test should be as much similar to the production usage as possible, however in general terms I would suggest the following.

At first find the optimal number of threads. Usually when you add the number of threads, the response time gets higher, but still TPS (transactions per second) goes up. If you add more threads, even the TPS decreases and the performance deteriorate (the system is overloaded).

Then run your test with the optimal number of threads. Probably you won't need to run the test for an entire hour, 5 or 10 minutes could be sufficient (the system usually shows the same behavior afterwards).

Please note that SoapUI consumes lots of your laptop (test station) resources, so your results can be malformed by the load on your laptop. Better is to run the SoapUI load test from the command line. For more performant systems I prefer using JMeter, which consumes less resources at the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will proceed with the existing one in SOAPUI. I'm running into an issue with keystore security for the web services load test when using the Jmeter, hence I'm only looking into SOAP UI.